# Connecting PostgreSQL/PostGIS and MapGuide Maestro

Tags: postgis, postgresql, web-mapping, mapguide

This is less a specific question, but hopefully more of an open question. There is little documentation regarding connecting the excellent OS web mapping software MapGuide Maestro (http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/wiki/maestro) with PostgreSQL/PostGIS (http://postgis.net/).

Can anyone give pointers on the connection of these two?

Answer (score 2):

If your postgis is setup correctly, connecting to Maestro should be fairly straight forward!

Have you tried the following:
http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/wiki/maestro/UserGuides/RDBMSFeatureSource